# Is this script that convert number to another digit is good?

Tags: javascript

Noob is here. I am don't know JavaScript why asking here. Sorry for my english. The purpose of the script make number (like 1,34,664) to another digit (like this (3 digit): 001,034,664).
Here is codes:

```
//Get number
let num = 45
//Convert it
let counter = num.toString().padStart(4, "0")
//Result of thi is 0045
```

Another code:

```
var i =1
var count = i + '';
while (count.length < 3) {
  count = '0' + count;
}
```

Second one gets value automatically but function of this script is same (I think so).
Which one is best?
Is there better way?

Comment: `num.toString(10).padStart(4, "0")`...

Comment: What is this mean?

Comment: if you use toString  don't miss to indicate the base to use

Comment: What base mean?

Comment: If your source *will* have commas on string, then you can split it and pad the first element with zeroes.

Comment: 10 is decimal, 2 is binary, 16 is hexadecimal  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Parameters

Comment: Both works well, you could also use ("000" + num).slice(-3) which slices the string from the end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both of them are good. In general, do not reinvent the wheel, so the first is a little better.

Comment: This "answer" is better off in comments